# RAM - Different between Commit Memory and Working Set

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, ram, resource-monitor

[image]

Is commit memory = Standby memory, Working Set = In Use memory ?

Comment: Short answer: `commit` is memory used backed by RAM / Pagefile; `working set` is all available pointers, including open file handlers. Long answer: [Commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge), [WS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set)

Comment: But I am a bit troubled about normally user only see **In Use** and **Standby**. How to put commit or working set into **In Use** and **Standby**

Comment: From reseach only talk about `commit` and `working set` description. `working set` in category of process and `commit` category by memory. Then a application actually physical memory using is, how to get?

Comment: Commit is memory that is hot and ready to go from RAM, where some of the memory in ws may be application dependencies which are currently being used, but may be backed by a file on disk, i.e., the VM has accessed some bytes on the virtual HDD, they were allocated to the ws, but are not kept in the hypervisor's commit space.

Comment: See [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: So, mean that application memory usage in `resource monitor` (`working set` & `committed`) can possible included `virtual memory` and `physical memory`? Why i want to know just Is `working set` & `commit memory` **Equal(=)** to memory usage **(Standby & In Use)**. How to know total usage of an application. Working set + commit memory?

Comment: @MattClark thanks for your reply. i no clear different between commit vs working set vs In Use vs Standby, how to know accurately an process usage.